# How to use parameter to set the path for script task SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

I need to set the directory path in the script task component in SSIS package.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to build the SSIS package inside that I have one action where in i need to create the folder hierarchy.

Instead of hard coding I need to set with parameter so that when they run the package they can change the folder path.

where I can set the parameter to perform dynamic action.

```
string _FileDirectory = @"C:/EPLInterface/PPSExtractor/";
```

Also how to access the created parameter in visual studio 2008 to build the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable in the control Flow like below

[image]

once you create variable open the script editor and add the variable u created some thing like below

note* : Variable what you have created will automatically appear here.

[image]

Then Click on Edit Script and access the variable as below:

```
if (Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value !=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    _FileDirectory = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString() + "\\";
                }
```

If you want to change this path Dynamically you can do it something like below:

```
dtexec /FILE "C:\Users\kata\Desktop\ExtractData.dtsx" /Set \Package.Variables[User::FilePath].Properties[Value];"C:\Newpath"
```

Also you can change when u run the SSIS package as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package level variable.  Variables can be set by the user at run time and read by your script task.